# how to pass dynamic data from parent to child ng-content in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-ui

I have a component flyout . It's a simple component that you wrap around any content/components that you wish to fly out from the side of the web page. We use it for the file upload. The component uses the broadcast service to listen for messages that tell it when to show and when to hide. It uses content projection `(<ng-content></ng-content>)` to allow you to pass any content to it.  how can I pass data from a parent container `(e.g., <flyout> )` to a child component that's dynamic - meaning, the child component for flyout will always be different.

flyout component:

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'open': show }" class="offcanvas-collapse" [attr.aria-hidden]="show ? 'false': 'true'">
    <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-end pv2">
      <button class="btn button-secondary-link" type="button" (click)="closeFlyout()">
        <span class="nav-text h5 mb0 underline fw7">Close</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

i read about ng-template-outlet but to make flyout component generic (so you can wrap it around any component/content and turn that component/content into a flyout) we use content projection. These ng-template-outlet approach look like the flyout would need to know something about its potential children, which makes it less flexible.

I am looking for other possible ways to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to get a reference to the child using @ContentChild